# how to open a resource located on my local server on my mobile browser?

Tags: android, localhost

I have a `file on my local server` (localhost) on my computer. I want to open the file on my android phone's browser which is in the `same wifi` network as my local computer. How can I do this?

Comment: Use es file explorer app .

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do this programmatically or just from a users point of view?

**As a user:** Use some kind of filebrowser on your mobile device and somehow share the file (Samba, NFS, etc.) on your localhost. There are dozen ways to do this and hard to sugggest the best way without knowing your setup.

**In code**: On your localhost, provide the file with a server based approach. For example, set up an web server to host the file via HTTP and access the file from your smartphone via an HTTP library (OKHttp, etc.) Or use a different protocol that fits your use case (again, Samba or something else).

For a better answer, please provide more information about your local setup.